# Why this code doesn't return the right result(8.675)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

So I'm passing this challenge from [freecodecamp](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/functional-programming/use-the-reduce-method-to-analyze-data)

And I wrote the code and it worked, however, the browser didn't respond at some moment and so I had to close it, closing it caused the code to be gone and I had to write another one, the problem is that when I wrote the new code, it doesn't return the right answer(it returns 2.)

Can you explain to me why that happens? And please, don't give me the direct answer, just tell me why that happens and how I fix it, that's all.

This is my code:

```js
// the global variable
var watchList = [{
    "Title": "Inception",
    "Year": "2010",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "16 Jul 2010",
    "Runtime": "148 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page, Tom Hardy",
    "Plot": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.",
    "Language": "English, Japanese, French",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 4 Oscars. Another 143 wins & 198 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.8",
    "imdbVotes": "1,446,708",
    "imdbID": "tt1375666",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "Year": "2014",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "07 Nov 2014",
    "Runtime": "169 min",
    "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Ellen Burstyn, Matthew McConaughey, Mackenzie Foy, John Lithgow",
    "Plot": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 1 Oscar. Another 39 wins & 132 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    "imdbVotes": "910,366",
    "imdbID": "tt0816692",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "The Dark Knight",
    "Year": "2008",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Jul 2008",
    "Runtime": "152 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters)",
    "Actors": "Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine",
    "Plot": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice.",
    "Language": "English, Mandarin",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 146 wins & 142 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "82",
    "imdbRating": "9.0",
    "imdbVotes": "1,652,832",
    "imdbID": "tt0468569",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "Year": "2005",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "15 Jun 2005",
    "Runtime": "140 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
    "Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
    "Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
    "Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 66 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "70",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    "imdbVotes": "972,584",
    "imdbID": "tt0372784",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Dec 2009",
    "Runtime": "162 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Director": "James Cameron",
    "Writer": "James Cameron",
    "Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
    "Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
    "Language": "English, Spanish",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "83",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
    "imdbVotes": "876,575",
    "imdbID": "tt0499549",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  }
];

// Add your code below this line
var arr = [];
watchList.map(item => {
  if (item.Director === "Christopher Nolan") {
    arr.push(Number(item.imdbRating));
  }
});
var averageRating = arr.reduce((before, after) => {
  return (before + after) / arr.length;
});

// Add your code above this line

console.log(averageRating);
```

And please, if I did a mistake by posting this question here(which happens a lot) then tell me and I will fix it.

Comment: The `.map` and `.reduce` implementations are definitely wrong, but your code does not have any actual errors, see the snippet.

Comment: where did you get error?

Comment: Umm, weird. I really don't know what happens with firefox console recently. However, it doesn't return the right calculation, how I fix that?

Comment: @TechnoKnight You have a logical error, i have corrected it in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in your code which returning you wrong value. 
Problem is, you are dividing avg rating by array length each time you are iterating over array using reduce.

```
return (before + after) / arr.length;
```

It should be

```
return (before + after);
```

and you should devide by array length in last like -

```
averageRating  = averageRating/arr.length;
```

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it some time ago before you respond, but instead of re-assigning the variable, I wrote var averageRating = arr.reduce((before, after) => before + after) / arr.length; so that it does like you exactly say. Thank you for further explaining, I'm not used to using these callback functions especially reduce, thanks again!

Comment: @TechnoKnight Yeah, no issue, point was to find out logical error:)